# Swift Firebase observe with .childAdded retrieving duplicate data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `UICollectionViewController` which acts as a feed that retrieves and displays data from my Firebase database. It's the window's root view controller, so it always exists. My issue is that every time the controller appears, all of the children from its observed node get added to the collection view. This is fine initially, but when I leave the controller and return, all of the same data gets appended, creating duplicates. Here is some pseudo-code, representing my interaction with Firebase:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var children_query: DatabaseQuery!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.children_query = Database.database().reference().child("children").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.observeAddedChildren()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.children_query.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func observeAddedChildren() {
        self.children_query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
        })
    }

}
```

In this pseudo-code, instead of dealing with UI, I simply print `snapshot`, but the point remains. All of the children get printed each time the controller appears. How can I retrieve *only* data that hasn't been retrieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Firebase, but when you pass a block to the `observe` function, there's nothing to suggest the observation stops when the view disappears.

So I wonder if calling `observe` multiple times is the problem. Have you tried calling `observe` just once, in ViewDidLoad?

Alternatively, have a property to record whether the observation has been started:

```
var observing: Bool = false

func observeAddedChildren() {
    if observing {
        return false
    }

    self.children_query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value)
    })
    observing = true
}
```

**Edit:** here's a couple more ways, because you're presumably adding the `snapshot` items to an array or other collection, then your `UICollectionViewDataSource` is reading stuff from that array.

So either:

1. empty this array inside `viewWillAppear` and then call `self.collectionView.reloadData()`, or
2. if your `snapshot` object has a unique identifier property, then put this into an array, and then the observe block can ignore items it's already seen before

Like this:

```
var snapshotIDs : [String] = Array<String>()

func observeAddedChildren() {
    self.children_query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if !snapshotIDs.contains(snapshot.uniqueID) {
            print(snapshot.value)
            snapshotIDs.append(snapshot.uniqueID)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Well I'm calling `self.children_query.removeAllObservers()` in `viewWillDisappear` and ultimately I don't want to keep observing when the view is not visible. But good idea; I might be able to fix the problem like this.

Comment: I get it. But if you're calling `removeAllObservers`, then `observe` when the view becomes visible again, the thing you're observing has no idea that you've added some items to your collection view already. So either (1) remove all items from your collection view in `viewWillAppear`, or (2) _you_ must keep track of which items have already been added, perhaps in an array, and ignore them if they're seen again in your observer block.